# How to give read and write permissions to a user to my database?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-permissions

I am looking for a way to guarantee read and write permissions to my database to another user in my network.
I know Microsoft SQL Server Management lets my add users by right clicking on the user section
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5G0.png)
and filling this
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfXu1.png).

Still, I am not sure what my Login name should be. For example, If I want to guarantee permission to the Administrator of a computer named GOR-PC, what should I enter?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GOR-PC\Administrator`.

However, adding local users to your SQL Server is generally a bad idea.
Ideally, you should use Active Directory users (in the form `DomainName\UserName`). This guarantees that the permissions you grant are independent of the existing of a PC or server.

Answer (score -1):

First you should create a user or group for the administrator on the server level that is under the general "Security" tab below the dabases: Security->Login->create. 
After tahat you can use the same login name you just created under the specific databse and Beowse the user and after that give the user read and write permission. 
Hope that helps.